# Can't generate random number

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to generate random numbers in a loop. I make an instance of the Random class before the loop starts, but it is inaccessible. The error i get is:

> 'System.Random.Sample()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

My code is:

```
Random random = new Random();
   while (ready == false)
   {
       double h = random.Sample();
   //Lots of things done here
   }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain the downvote, and how I can improve my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.sample(v=vs.110).aspx) of the Sample method explains this behaviour:

> **Important**
>
> The Sample method is **protected**, which means that it is accessible only within the Random class and its derived classes. To generate a random number between 0 and 1 from a Random instance, call the [NextDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

The purpose of the `Sample` method is to override it if you want to create your own, custom random number generator. If you just want to *use* the `Random` class, `NextDouble` is the correct method to call.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [`NextDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

```
 double h = random.NextDouble();
```

The method you are trying to call is not `public` as stated in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

To use the **protected** Sample method, you need to "derive a class from the Random class and override the Sample method", according to the documentation.

What you need is NextDouble(), which returns a random floating-point number that is greater than or equal to 0.0, and less than 1.0.

Please see the documentation below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Use

```
double h = random.NextDouble();
```

Instead.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain the downvote, and how I can improve my answer? Thanks.